# Gyrating particle transmission through rectangle: NIntegrate or something faster?

Tags: numerical-integration, compile

I need a function that tells me, what transmission a gyrating particle has through a rectangular aperture if you consider all phase angles. So for a specific guiding center position and gyration radius, only part of the circle can go through the opening. I have to evaluate this function a lot of times (in the scope of a multidimensional numerical integration), so I want it to be **as effective as possible**.

**TLDR:** What is the best (fastest, acceptable accuracy) approach, to calculate a fraction of a circle through a rectangular region?

---

The **main option** I have investigated so far:

Define an `ImplicitRegion` for a rectangle + a circle and then do `NIntegrate` (or `RegionMeasure` - which should effectively be the same but is slower) on the region.

The `ImplicitRegion` includes parameters for the rectangular opening (xA and yA), offsets of the coordinate system (xOff, yOff), guiding center positions (xGC and yGC) as well as a radius r.

```
CircleInRectangle[xA_, yA_, xOff_, yOff_, xGC_, yGC_, r_] =
 ImplicitRegion[
  -xA/2 + xOff <= x <= xA/2 + xOff && 
  -yA/2 + yOff <= y <= yA/2 + yOff &&
  {x, y} \[Element] Circle[{xGC, yGC}, r]
  (*&&{x,y,xA,yA,xOff,yOff,xGC,yGC,r}\[Element]Reals*),
  {x, y}]
```

A visualization for an examplatory parameter set looks like the following:

[image: Central guiding center]

I can then either do `RegionMeasure` of the region or a `NIntegrate[1,{x,y} \[Element] region]` divided by $2\pi r$. With those methods, I can also control the accuracy of my result (with `PrecisionGoal`), which is good!

A **mediocre second option** I investigated:

Create a list of equidistant (with regards to an angle phi of the circle) points on the circle and check for all of them, how many are inside the rectangle (with `Count`). The accuracy of course depends on the number of points I use.

---

**Piecewise**

For both options, I also wrap around a `Piecewise` function to directly return 0 if the circle is entirely out of range or if the gyration radius is very small, then I just return 1 or 0.

---

**Accuracy**

For some reason, the evaluation time of Option one doesn't significantly increase if I increase `PrecisionGoal` of the integration. For a set of multidimensional parameter points of N=9801, the calculation time is between 90 and 92 seconds (for `PrecisionGoal` 1 to 4)!

For option two, the time increases of course linearly with the number of steps. At approximately 500 steps, the time is equivalent to Option one. In general, I would expect the accuracy to be a little less than Option one. One could even give an analytic upper bound for the accuracy of option two. First estimations suggest, that I would need more than the 500 points to get a relative precision of $10^{-3}$.

---

**Possible 3rd option**

I could in principle make a lot of `Which` cases and then calculate the fraction of the circular arc analytically, but I think the number of cases is very high and complex, which is why I haven't tried that yet.

---

**My question**: What is the fastest (with still acceptable accuracy of maybe $10^{-3}$ relative) way of calculating the transmission. Is it a fine tuning of one of the above options, or something completely different?

---

A last note: **Compile**

Would compiling the functions help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question doesn't involve any integration. You can describe any union of circle arcs with `Interval` of angles (union of angle intervals).

```
IntersectionAngles[x_] := Piecewise[{
  { {0, 0},      x<=-1},
  { {0, 2\[Pi]}, x>= 1},
  { {ArcCos[x], 2\[Pi]-ArcCos[x]},  True}}];

IntervalMod[{min_,max_}] := Interval@@Piecewise[{
  { {{0,max-2\[Pi]}, {min,2\[Pi]}}, min<=2\[Pi]<=max},
  { {Mod[{min,max},2\[Pi]]},  True}
}];

CircleInRectangle[xA_,yA_,xOff_,yOff_,xGC_,yGC_,r_]:=
  Module[{
    arr = {xOff-xGC+xA/2,
           yOff-yGC+yA/2,
         -(xOff-xGC-xA/2),
         -(yOff-yGC-yA/2)}/r,
    int},
    int = IntervalIntersection@@Table[
      IntervalMod[IntersectionAngles[arr[[i]]]+(i-1)\[Pi]/2],
    {i,4}];
  r RegionMeasure[int]
]

In[641]:= Timing[CircleInRectangle[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1]]

Out[641]= {0.000399, 3.13015}
```

Since you are working with just arithmetics, you can control accuracy and precision as much as you like. If you enter precise values, you will get precise answer:

```
In[681]:= Timing[CircleInRectangle[15/8, 2, -1/3, -1, -1/16, -Sqrt[23/123], 1]]

Out[681]= {0.001364, (3 \[Pi])/2 - ArcCos[2/3] - ArcCos[Sqrt[23/123]]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. There is a minor issue (piecewise needs another {}), but other than that, a very interesting solution. I have to look into it at test timing results.

Comment: I had some time to investigate your function. For very specific parameter sets, I got a RegionMeasure = 1 instead of 0. I had to provide RegionMeasure with the dimenions = 1, otherwise it would have counted the number of points for some reason (dim = 0). I am accepting your answer as it is very much faster than my solutions! Thank you